# Elasticsearch curator - "--older-than 6"

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

When i try to use "*curator --host 127.0.0.1 delete --older-than 6*" i get the error 
"*Error: no such option: --older-than*" i'm running the newest verison of curator, any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: mention indices like curator --host 10.0.0.2 delete indices --older-than 30

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the sub-command 'indices' between 'delete' and '--older-than'

You will also need other flags to get a complete command-line based on your index name pattern.